# Inductance of a coated cylinder

Tags: magnetic-fields, inductance

Say we have an infinite cylinder, through which a current of intensity $I$ flows. Say this cylinder is coated with a conductive material, of negligible thickness, through which a current of the same intensity flows, but in the opposite sense. What is the inductance of this system? I know how to calculate the inductance for the infinite cylinder, but the layer of conductive material confuses me. The radius of the cylinder and free space magnetic permeability are also given.

Comment: Saying "this system", probably means the mutual inductance, not the self-inductance.

Comment: I just added the term myself to make it clear that I see them as an assemble, I mean the total inductance